# SQL Find if a product has been ordered by a customer within the last 12 months

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have been racking my brains out over the thanksgiving holiday an have had no luck in doing the following.

I run the following SQL script to get the last twelve months of data from our sales database. While this has returned every sale as I had wanted for another report it has been asked of me to now search the results and find out if the product has been ordered before and if not to return the results to another report.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
SELECT 
    cicmpy.cmp_name AS "Company Name", 
    humres.fullname AS "Salesperson", 
    oehdrhst_sql.ord_dt AS "Order Date", 
    oelinhst_sql.item_no AS "Item Number", 
    oelinhst_sql.item_desc_1 AS "Description",
    oelinhst_sql.qty_ordered AS "Qty Ordered", 
    oelinhst_sql.item_desc_2 AS "UPC CODE",   
    oehdrhst_sql.oe_po_no AS "Customer PO"
FROM   
    (humres humres 
INNER JOIN 
    (cicmpy cicmpy 
INNER JOIN 
    oehdrhst_sql oehdrhst_sql ON cicmpy.cmp_code=oehdrhst_sql.cus_no) 
    ON humres.res_id=oehdrhst_sql.slspsn_no) 
INNER JOIN 
    oelinhst_sql oelinhst_sql ON oehdrhst_sql.ord_no = oelinhst_sql.ord_no
WHERE  
    oehdrhst_sql.ord_dt > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY 
    cicmpy.cmp_name, oelinhst_sql.item_no
```

The above returns my data in the following format

```
Company Name    Salesperson Order Date  Item Number Description Qty Ordered UPC CODE    Customer PO
Company 1       John Doe    12/29/2014  1200052     Product 1            90 0000000001      292072
Company 1       John Doe    4/7/2015    1200053     Product 2            90 0000000002      348615
Company 1       John Doe    6/2/2015    1200052     Product 1            90 0000000001      382184
Company 2       Jane Doe    12/29/2014  1200052     Product 1            90 0000000001      292072
Company 2       Jane Doe    4/7/2015    1200053     Product 2            90 0000000002      348615
Company 2       Jane Doe    6/2/2015    1200052     Product 1            90 0000000001      382184
Company 3       Jane Doe    12/29/2014  1200052     Product 1            90 0000000001      292072
Company 3       Jane Doe    4/7/2015    1200053     Product 2            90 0000000002      348615
Company 3       John Smith  6/2/2015    1200053     Product 2            90 0000000002      382184
Company 3       John Smith  12/29/2014  1200052     Product 1            90 0000000001      292072
Company 3       John Smith  4/7/2015    1200053     Product 2            90 0000000002      348615
Company 3       John Smith  6/2/2015    1200052     Product 1            90 0000000001      382184
```

I have thought of using COUNT but I can not figure how to limit it by customer name also I toyed around with using Distinct but I could not figure it out either. Any help would be appreciate as I can not continue dumping 20,000+ lines of sales to excel to filter them for this single report.

it has been asked of me to search within the results (as in the example above) and find out if the product has been ordered before and if not to return the results to another report. effectively doing a query against these results ie. a new product is released with item number 1200053 when company 1 places an order for this item it is not in their previous purchases so the following needs returned

```
Company Name    Salesperson Order Date  Item Number Description Qty Ordered UPC CODE    Customer PO
Company 1       John Doe    12/29/2015  1200053     Product 3            90 0000000001      292999
```

Comment: "What" "is" "with" "all" "of" "the" "double" "quotes"?

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove them as I adjusted this same query for a crystal report as well so KS event manager could automate the report.

Comment: that should be better thanks for pointing out my oversight.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your desired results are.

Comment: it has been asked of me to search within the results (as in the example above) and find out if the product has been ordered before and if not to return the results to another report. effectively doing a query against these results ie. a new product is released with item number 1200053 when company 1 places an order for this item it is not in their previous purchases so the following needs returned

Comment: (company name) (Salesperson)  (Order Date)    (Item Number)  (Description)   (qty ordered) (UPC)

Comment: Why are you aliasing all your tables with the name of the table? That kind of defeats the point of using an alias.

Comment: as with (item_desc_2  AS  UPC Code) this needs to be "common" as I may know what the database field is but the salespeople in the field will not this report will be automated to the salespeople through email so I did this to avoid confusion on their part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only include customers who have not purchased the product prior to your DATE, simply add a `NOT EXISTS (<Some Query>)` condition to your where clause.

EDIT: Further explanation, the `NOT EXISTS` will check to see the customer has historically ordered the item and if not, return that customer in your results.

See below.

```
DECLARE @GT DATETIME
SET @GT = GETDATE();

SELECT 
    cicmpy.cmp_name AS [Company Name], 
    humres.fullname AS [Salesperson], 
    oehdrhst_sql.ord_dt AS [Order Date], 
    oelinhst_sql.item_no AS [Item Number], 
    oelinhst_sql.item_desc_1 AS [Description],
    oelinhst_sql.qty_ordered AS [Qty Ordered], 
    oelinhst_sql.item_desc_2 AS [UPC CODE],   
    oehdrhst_sql.oe_po_no AS [Customer PO]
FROM cicmpy cicmpy 
INNER JOIN oehdrhst_sql oehdrhst_sql 
    ON cicmpy.cmp_code = oehdrhst_sql.cus_no
INNER JOIN humres humres 
    ON humres.res_id = oehdrhst_sql.slspsn_no
INNER JOIN oelinhst_sql oelinhst_sql 
    ON oehdrhst_sql.ord_no = oelinhst_sql.ord_no
WHERE oehdrhst_sql.ord_dt > DATEADD(year, -1, @GT)
    AND NOT EXISTS  --Exclude those customers identified in the sub query below.
                    (
                        --Identify customers where the item was purchased previously.
                        select *
                        from cicmpy c 
                        INNER JOIN oehdrhst_sql oh 
                            ON  c.cmp_code = oh.cus_no
                        INNER JOIN oelinhst_sql ol
                            ON oh.ord_no = ol.ord_no
                        where c.cmp_code = oehdrhst_sql.cmp_code
                            and ol.item_no = oelinhst_sql.item_no
                            and ol.ord_dt <= DATEADD(year, -1, @GT)
                    )
ORDER BY 
    cicmpy.cmp_name, oelinhst_sql.item_no;
```

Hope this helps!